# We have some work to do for this site

Tags: discussion

According to [the statistics on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language), we are in trouble:

1. 19.6 questions per day: It says 10 questions per day on average is a healthy data, but we now depend on one particular user for a majority of questions.
2. We have 231 visits per day. It says 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work.

It's been only four days and I know it is too early to worry about these numbers. But I saw what happened to [Language Learning Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) that has only one question and 38 visits per day. They are not doing very well and there is no guarantee we won't face the same situation in the foreseeable future.

Here are some numbers for [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language) and [English Language and Usage Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1269/english-language-usage) which are doing very well.

I suggest we do the followings:

1. Visit Korean Language SE as often as possible.
2. Try to contribute more by asking and answering more.
3. Tell your friends and colleagues about this site so that we can have more new users.
4. We need to be [friendly and nice](https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) to new users and upvote questions and answers that are useful and helpful.

Until we have bigger user base, we will certainly need more efforts and contribution from existing users. 힘냅시다.

Comment: You're a little mistaken, actually. The numbers really don't matter unless they're *abysmally* bad. Language Learning is a healthy little beta site - its days are not numbered.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I am not sure how you define "healthy" and we will know how it will end up in a few months. I have watched quality of the questions asked on LL SE since its launch and it doesn't seem to work very well. There are no more questions to ask there. I will call 0.9 questions and 36 visits per day 'disastrous' if it is not abysmally bad.

Comment: [opensource.se] had very similar stats to LL at the start of its life; it's now a successful beta. There is *very* little you can tell from raw numbers or at-a-glance observations, especially at an early stage.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Good for Open Source. I edited my post as it doesn't sound politically correct. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we need to worry *that* much.

Here is my analysis on the [current stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language):

- **16.7 questions per days**
  *(10 is a healthy beta)*
  Even if we don't count the questions asked by the user you mentioned ([/u/topo-morto](https://korean.stackexchange.com/users/64/topo-morto) if I'm correct) we're still above 10. 130 users have signed up for the beta.
- **97% answered**
  *(90% is a healthy beta)*
  It's a good score, but I admit that given the topic of this community, it's really easy to achieve. For example, [French.SE has 100%](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language), [Russian.SE has 100%](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language), [Italian.SE has 98%](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language), etc… but maybe their high score is due to being out of the private beta.
- **22 avid users (200+ rep) / 243 total users**
  *(150 users with 200+ rep, 10 with 2000+ rep, 5 with 3000+ rep)*
  It's been only 5 days, I think it's hard to judge. At least for me.
- **1.8 answer per question**
  *(2.5 is a healthy beta)*
  It's not that good, but it's not bad either. For example, [French.SE has 2.3](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language), [Russian.SE has 2.7](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10848/russian-language) and [Italian.SE has 1.8](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language). Perhaps we could improve that score.
- **204 visits/day**
  *(1,500 visits per day is a healthy beta)*
  Well, it's a private beta, no one expects it to achieve that score.

So, to react to the title of your post, I don't think we *have to* do some work, but perhaps we *could* do some efforts to improve this proposal.

About the rest of your post (with your recommandations), I agree, except for the first one: playing with the number might not be very helpful in the long run.

Comment: @Rathony: Edited! I tried to find a way to convey my thoughts correctly, but I struggled with that word. It might be better now?

Comment: @Rathony: well, a new day just started, that's why this number is so low at the moment. Most of the users might be sleeping. This stat doesn't take this into account ;)

Comment: Because I (mis?)understood your first point as a way to improve that statistic. I apologise if I sounded rude, no offense meant. :) You are free to edit my post to fix what I might have misunderstood. However, users visiting this site don't increase the number of users, your third point does though!

Comment: If users visit this site more often than they do now like every day instead of once in every two or three days, it will improve the number of visits per day and the statistics will not show such a dismal number. I will delete my previous comments.

Comment: It's been approximately 27  hours since I posted the question and the number is still 204 visits per day. I don't think the number is updated real-time as it is not changing, which means it doesn't matter whether users are sleeping at a specific time zone.

Comment: @Rathony I would imagine it's a windowed average? The window may even be longer than the time the site has been going, in which case I'd expect the number to slowly fall following the initial spike of interest when the beta started..

Comment: 205 visits per day right now, so we've stopped the rot :)

Comment: @topomorto Now it is at 178 visits with 15.9 questions per day and I expect these numbers will go down continuously unless we make some efforts to attract new users.

Comment: @Rathony http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104804/233916 may be relevant. I *think* we are doing a decent job of the private beta, as long as we keep adding a few questions per day. Hopefully when the public beta starts, we'll get another little spike and then be able to keep up some momentum.

Comment: But I also don't think there's any harm in trying to lure in a few new users!

Comment: @topomorto Yes, I posted the question just for that purpose. I don't want to see Korean SE go down like Language Learners.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how bad these stats are for the early stages of a private beta, but in any case, those are all great suggestions! We have actually been pretty good at answering questions, so we can probably manage a few more questions asked. Ideas for 'inspiration' are:

- any funny turns of phrase in a favourite song or movie
- try harder to speak Korean with your Korean friends/family - this often reveals your own areas of confusion
- questions on other Korean language sites (we shouldn't copy content, but it should be easy enough to come up with some good similar questions)
- highly-rated questions on other SE language sites - maybe there are some equivalent questions about Korean?

I also think the thing about being friendly is really important. Stack Exchange can encourage some behaviours that are rather unfriendly, so I'd recommend a constructive comment rather than a downvote or close vote wherever possible (We've also been great at improving things based on comments).

The positive cycle we should aim for is

- come here, and contribute by asking, answering, and voting
- the site becomes a more rewarding and informative place to visit
- people come here, and contribute...